# spinner while submiting a form angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

How to add a spinner while my form is submiting (then it goes to another /route)

What I've already done is bellow.

**Angularjs**

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    $http.post('/option', {
        firstName: $scope.firstName,
        lastName: $scope.lastName,
    }).then(function(res) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("flight", JSON.stringify(res.data));

        $location.path("/option");
        $scope.setDelay = function(){
            $scope.delay = true;
            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.delay = false;
            }, 2000);
        };
        });
```

**HTML**

*Button submit (I want to show the spinner when I click onSubmit())*

```
<md-button name="submit" ng-click="submit(); setDelay()" class="md-raised">Find</md-button>
```

*`<div>` which shows the spinner*

```
<div class="loading-div" ng-show="delay">
    <img src="spinner.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: What happens now? Error or nothing or it shows up late?

Comment: @JoeLloyd no error it works, but it shows up just before the page change, so there is no "forced sleep moment" while its changing of page. Am I clear ?

Answer (score 0):

1 in your submit function, set $scope.delay = true;

2 in post return .then(function(res){, set $scope.delay = false;

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can hande the loading flag inside your submit method:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.delay = true; //but I would name it as loading :P
    $http.post('/option', {
        firstName: $scope.firstName,
        lastName: $scope.lastName,
    }).then(function(res) {
        $scope.delay = false;
        sessionStorage.setItem("flight", JSON.stringify(res.data));
        $location.path("/option");
    });
```

Then your html just need to call submit function:

```
<md-button name="submit" ng-click="submit();" class="md-raised">Find</md-button>
```

Anyway, your setDelay function ws defined inside your success callback from $http.post, and I was wrong.

Comment: Yes it works but I would like to force on purpose the sleeping moment a bit longer. With those solutions, it does not sleep how much time I want. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: then wrap the $scope.delay = false; with `$timeout(function(){
                $scope.delay = false;
            }, 2000);`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to be exactly 2 seconds, or you think that's what it might take for user to hear back from the server? If it's second option, then you should toggle your boolean before http request like this:

```
$scope.submit = () => {
    $scope.delay = true;
    $http.post('/option', {
      firstName: $scope.firstName,
      lastName: $scope.lastName,
    }).then(res => {
      sessionStorage.setItem("flight", JSON.stringify(res.data));
      $scope.delay = false;
      $location.path("/option");
   })
}
```

and HTML

```
<md-button name="submit" ng-click="submit()" class="md-raised">Find</md-button>
<div class="loading-div" ng-if="delay">
  <img src="spinner.gif">
</div>
```

That should do it

Answer (score 0):

```
<md-button name="submit" ng-click="submit()" class="md-raised">Find</md-button>

<div class="loading-div" ng-if="delay">
   <img src="spinner.gif">
</div>



$scope.submit = function() {
  $scope.delay = true;
  $http.post('/option', {
    firstName: $scope.firstName,
    lastName: $scope.lastName,
   }).then(function(res) {
      sessionStorage.setItem("flight", JSON.stringify(res.data));
      $scope.delay = false;
      $location.path("/option");
  });
}
```